# System.TypeLoadException: Types extending from COM objects should override all methods of an interface implemented by the base COM class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vb.net

Ok, here is the situation. I am looking to get a custom arcobjects vb.net extension running correctly on ArcMap10.5. When loading nodes in an attachment viewer I receive the following error once Private Sub LoadNodes() is called.

System.TypeLoadException: Types extending from COM objects should override all methods of an interface implemented by the base COM class.

If I remove these lines from LoadNodes() I don't get the System.TypeLoadException: and the program runs through LoadNodes() but obviuously fails because the Attachment table is missing.

```
   ' Get relAttachments table and set selection table for it
    Dim relAttach As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTable = New cAttachStandAloneTable(mFWS.OpenTable(modDBNaming.GetQualifiedTableName("RelAttachments", mFWS)), "FCName")
    mRelAttachSel = relAttach
```

Somehow this issue is related to the newer environment because this issue does not occur in the old environment.

Current Environment: Visual Studio 13 .net framework 4.5 ArcMap and Arcobjects 10.5 (10.4 has the same issue)

Old Environment: Visual Studio 8 .net framework 3.5 ArcMap and ArcAobjects 10.2.2 and older

Here are the beginning steps of LoadNodes()

```
Private Sub LoadNodes()
    Try
        lblStatus.Text = "Populating the tree view with the database layers"
        Me.Cursor = Windows.Forms.Cursors.AppStarting

    ' Get relAttachments table and set selection table for it
    Dim relAttach As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTable = New cAttachStandAloneTable(mFWS.OpenTable(modDBNaming.GetQualifiedTableName("RelAttachments", mFWS)), "FCName")
    mRelAttachSel = relAttach

    ' Load relAttachments into dataset datatable
    PopulateRelAttachmentsTable(relAttach.Table)
    Dim relAttachDV As DataView = New DataView(mDataset.Tables("relAttachments"))

    ' Clear out reachnodes hashtable
    mReachNodes.Clear()

    ' Run through any selected features and store in table
    If mStandAlone = False Then
        PopulateSelectionTable()
    End If
    Dim selDV As DataView = New DataView(mDataset.Tables("Selection"))

    ' Clear the tree
    tvStream.Nodes.Clear()
```

Code from frmAttachViewer

```
' Load the dictionaries
            LoadDictionaries()
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded Dictionaries")

            ' Load the featureclass names into cboFeatureclass
            For Each de As DictionaryEntry In mLayerTab
                cboFeatureClass.Items.Add(de.Key)
            Next

            ' Load the tree view nodes
            LoadNodes()

            ' "Open" the reaches that have been selected (or features in them were selected)
            mSuppressSelChanges = False
            If mStandAlone = False Then
                MapSelectionChanged()
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            StreamAnalyst_AGS10.ErrorHandler.ShowErrors(ex, "Warn", "An error occurred while loading the form")
            log.Warn("An error occurred while loading the form", ex)
```

Comment: What is 'cAttachStandAloneTable'? That's not a type.

Comment: `Public Class cAttachStandAloneTable
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTableClass

    Private _DisplayField As String
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Table As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable
    Private _Valid As Boolean
    Private _SelectionSet As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISelectionSet`

Comment: Okay, what is the code for the relevant constructor? Or before that, is it one of the sub calls on that line that causes the error or the constructor for cAttachStandAloneTable.

Comment: I am not sure what the relevant constructor is but I added where they failure occurs. I walked it through through the LoadDictionaries() successfully but then one it hits LoadNodes() the next step when debugged is Catch ex As Exception.

Comment: Also as I mention in the original post, when the cAttachStandAloneTable line is removed, LoadNodes() does not cause the System Type load exception.

Comment: I may have misunderstood. So cAttachStandAloneTable is a Type, as you said, but as far as I can tell that type does not originate in ArcObjects and is a custom object written by you or someone else. If that's correct then the issue is likely that cAttachStandAloneTable has not fully implemented it's COM interfaces in v10.5 because new members were added in the newer version. So the cAttachStandAloneTable class would need to be updated to include the new interface members.

Comment: That seems to make sense and it is not from ArcObjects. ANy suggestion on how I can check to see if it has been implemented? or go about implementing cAttachStandAloneTable. I am unable to find cAttachStandAloneTable any where else inside the VS Solution besides when its called in LoadNodes() and above where it Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTableClass

Comment: Assuming it's coming from a .NET library or executable you can decompile cAttachStandAloneTable and see what is and isn't there (ILSpy works for this). You can copy and paste the decompiled code into VS and it will either work or be very close to it. Do you know what cAttachStandAloneTable does that regular StandAloneTable does not?

Comment: So here is the latest. cAttachStandAloneTable is causing the issue.